# How to verify a users domain before allowing access to my website?

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a website. This website does not have a database to store our employees user info. We are having them sign in using their Google account. If a person comes across our website, and they don't have the domain name email address, they are redirected on to an error page. Otherwise, if they have one of the 6 domains we currently host, they will be directed to our support page.

The problem I am having is that anyone with a google account can access the site and this can not happen.

On our log in page, we use the google login javascript as follows:

login.php

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
                // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
                var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this    directly to your server!
                console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

                // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
                var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);

                if (id_token !=""){
                    window.location = "login_process.php";
                    } 
             };
  </script>
```

From here, it points to our login_process.php page if the user enters their Google account info as normal. The code is below:

```
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $allowed = array('example.com', 'example.com', 'example.com', 'example.com', 'example.com', 'example.com', 'example.com');

// Make sure the address is valid
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
$explodedEmail = explode('@', $email);
$auth = array_pop($explodedEmail);

if ( ! in_array($auth, $allowed))
{
    // Not allowed
    header('Location: error.php');
  } 
}else
    {
        // Allowed
        header('Location: support.php')
    }
```

If your email address does not contain ONE of the required domains, it SHOULD redirect you to the error.php page. Otherwise, it will allow access to our support page.

For some reason that I am not understanding, no matter what google account you use, it is still allowing access to the support.php page. I feel I am missing a step here somewhere and I am not seeing where it is. Any help to get this to work would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your `$allowed`  array? And please, fix the `else` statement, you are writing parenthesis `else ( header('Location: support.php') )`

Comment: Sorry, was editing when you replied. The code is exactly as I have it now.

Comment: I think you have a reversed logic. It's better to redirect to support.php if it matches the domain, not opposite, because all errors you were getting in the `if` statement will produce the redirect to support.php. However, in your javascript you are making `window.location`  but you don't POST any form data, so  `$_POST[]`  in your PHP will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments, try this:

Reverse your logic in the if statement, to allow redirects to support.php only if it's matched the domain, not always except doesn't match.

```
if ( in_array($auth, $allowed))
{
   // allowed
    header('Location: support.php');
} else {
    // not allowed
    header('Location: error.php')
}
```

Your javascript makes a redirect but don't POST any form data, so  `$_POST` doesn't work in your php. You must to make a hidden form with an input hidden with the email and then submit with javascript.